# Taylor series approximation of Gaussian $Q$ function , $Q(x) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int_x^\infty {{e^{ - \frac{{{v^2}}}{2}}}dv}$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, taylor-expansion, regression-analysis

$ \require{newcommand}\newcommand{\Erfc}{\operatorname{Erfc}}$

I am trying to find a Taylor series expansion for the Gaussian $Q$ function. I have seen that error function $\Erfc(x)$ is an approximation of $Q(x)$ (Is my assumption correct?).

$\Erfc(x)$ has a Taylor approximation. Is it possible to construct such for $Q(x)$ function? Is there any condition for that? Thank you.

Comment: If is not an approximation, it is a variant: $Q(x)=\frac12\text{erfc}(\frac x{\sqrt 2})$.

Comment: Use $\int_x^\infty=\int_0^\infty-\int_0^x$ and integrate the development of $e^{-x^2/2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain a Taylor series as follows:
\begin{align*}
Q(x) & = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t^2 /2} dt}  - \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int_0^x {e^{ - t^2 /2} dt}  = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int_0^x {e^{ - t^2 /2} dt} 
\\ &
 = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int_0^x {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n!}}\left( { - \frac{{t^2 }}{2}} \right)^n } dt}  = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n!}}\left( { - \frac{1}{2}} \right)^n \frac{{x^{2n + 1} }}{{2n + 1}}} .
\end{align*}
**Addendum:**
A different series expansion is
$$
Q(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}e^{ - x^2 /2} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{x^{2n + 1} }}{{1 \cdot 3 \cdots (2n + 1)}}} .
$$

Comment: Thank you. Does the second term of the result is always positive and less that 0.5 for any positive and negative $x$?

Comment: The sum with the prefactor $\frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}$ is at most $1/2$ in absolute value for any real $x$.